# Unable to run chefspec tests having databags

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec, databags

I am trying to run unit tests using chefspec. I added databags to my recipe. Without databags, chefspec test running fine. After adding databags chefspec showing below error:

```
 1) database::prerequisites installs a package
     Failure/Error: let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: 'oracle', version: '7.2').converge(described_recipe) }
 Net::HTTPServerException:
   404 "Not Found "
 # /tmp/chefspec20170616-8187-olziw2file_cache_path/cookbooks/database/recipes/prerequisites.rb:9:in `from_file'
 # ./prerequisites_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./prerequisites_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I dont know how to handle databags in chefspec. When i execute recipe using chef-client in workstation, it is working fine. but the chefspec testing is getting failed.

recipe spec file:

```
require 'chefspec'

describe 'database::prerequisites' do
  let(:chef_run) { ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: 'oracle', version: '7.2').converge(described_recipe) }



    before(:each) do
      stub_command("cat /etc/oracle-release | grep 7.*").and_return(true)
    end

    before(:each) do
      stub_command("cat /etc/oracle-release | grep 6.*").and_return(true)
    end

     before(:each) do
      stub_command("cat /etc/selinux/config | grep SELINUX=disabled").and_return(true)
    end

    before(:each) do
      stub_command("sestatus | grep enabled").and_return(true)
    end

  it 'installs a package ' do
    expect(chef_run).to install_package('oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall')
    expect(chef_run).to install_package('net-tools')
    expect(chef_run).to install_package('xorg-x11-apps')

  end

   it 'creates a directory with the default action' do
    expect(chef_run).to create_directory('/u01/app/oraInventory')
    expect(chef_run).to create_directory('/oradata')
  end  

end
```

recipe file:

```
my_secret_key = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/etc/secret_key")
passwords = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("databags", "databag_passwords", my_secret_key)
```

Could you please suggest how to solve this issue. I am running tests in my chef workstation only.

Comment: Why not using `data_bag_item` recipe DSL method ([Documentation here](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#data-bag-item)) ?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But still i got same error. chef recipe run went fine. but testing is giving same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the data bags in the test server, https://github.com/chefspec/chefspec#dsl shows how to do this using `ServerRunner` or you can use rspec-mocks and mock the `load_secret` and `load` methods. I prefer the latter as it is faster (in terms of test run time) and more unit-y but it's up to you.